# How to keep installation path while install my application and remove it while uninstalling it

Tags: visual-studio, environment-variables, setup-project, advanced-installer

I'm using VisualStudio 2022. I have to create a setup project for my C# WPF application in .NET Framework 4.8. The thing is, I have to add the installation path as an environment variable while installing the application. Also remove it while uninstalling the application.
I found command for add and remove environment variable. It is as below,

```
setx APPQ_Path "C:\Program Files\AppQ" /M
```

and

```
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v APPQ_Path /f
```

Plan is to keep this commands as batch files and execute it after installation and after uninstalling completed.
I got some indications as shown below
[image: Custom Actions]

1. Is it possible to execute a batch file using this way?
2. Installation path may change by user. So, I have to pass it to the first command as an argument. How to do?
3. This Environment variable setting need to run as admin while I tested with cmd window. How to do it from installation setup process?
4. Is there any other way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Are you planning on any cross platform capabilities? If not, and you're only targeting Windows, you can use the Registry to store the install path.

Comment: @Casey: For windows only. Now, I got Installer class and trying to work with "public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)"

Comment: Why do you use the option `/M` for a __machine__ wide registration, i.e. a __system__ environment variable? That requires the elevated privileges of a local administrator which most users in companies do not have at all. Why is the installation directory not stored with a simple REG_SZ value with name `AppPath` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\AppName` or using the default string of this registry key and the application reads that registry value? Or why is the application path not stored in a file `AppName.ini` in the directory `%APPDATA%\CompanyName\AppName`?

Comment: A system environment variable increases the memory usage of __all__ processes. Storing the application installation path in Windows registry (for current user) or in an INI file in application data directory (for current user) does not affect other processes at all and has the advantage that the application can be installed by any user without the need of elevated privileges of a local administrator as long as the user has the necessary permissions to install the application into the directory suggested or selected by the user.

Comment: The application path can be stored also in a file `AppName.ini` in the directory `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\CompanyName\AppName` for being available for all users. But that requires write permissions during the installation for the all users profile directory which means elevated privileges of a local administrator. Last but not least a real [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration) as described by Microsoft in the referenced documentation page could be done for current user only or local machine (all users with elevated privileges).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is there any other way to achieve this requirement?**

Yes. And, this answer removed my first 3 questions.
Also changed the plan to use environment variable. Now, it is creating a file with path in the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\CompanyName\AppName` as said in the Mofi's comment.

Here is how I did this.

1. Install 'Microsoft Visual studio installer' from 'Manage Extensions'.
2. Added a project to the solution of type 'Setup Wizard'.
3. Right click on the project and click on 'Custom Actions' from 'View' option.
   [image]
4. Add custom action for Install and Uninstall.
   [image]
5. Add value in the Properties window of custom action.
   [image]
6. Added an installer class in Startup project.
7. Use override methods of 'Install' and 'Uninstall' for writing the path into a file (I named it as 'AppData.txt') in a common user path. (I used `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`)
   [image]
8. Write logic to delete the 'AppData' file in uninstall method.

Note: We can use other override methods like 'OnAfterInstall' also.